# Capturar la pantalla por código en Android

Tags: android, screenshot

¿Cómo puedo realizar la captura de pantalla en Android Studio desde el Activity?

¿Algún link o tutorial? 
Cualquier respuesta será bienvenida

Answer (score 3):

Con la siguiente función creas un bitmap insertando un View que lo obtienes que la funcion :

> getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()

Después se escribe el bitmap en un File y se guarda con el nombre de la hora y la fecha actuales.
Debes de añadir el permiso de escritura en la memoria externa en tu manifiest.xml

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {

        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aqui puedes obtener un poco mas de información en una pregunta de [la comunidad de stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

Comment: Gracias!, y siento no haber sido mas especifico, ya que me refería a hacerlo desde la parte de programación.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, hora de hacer las pruebas!